# Parsing string in C using strtok and store in array

Tags: c, strtok

I am parsing a string using strtok.  The string I am parsing may have two possibilities like **"10,5"**  or **"10"**. When I parse **"10,5"** I can successfully put then into array, but when I have this **"10"** , I have 1 item 10 and another item a big integer in array.

here is my code

```
   int array[2];
   char *p = strtok (argv[1], ",");
   while (p != NULL)
   {
       array[n++] = atoi(p);
       p = strtok (NULL, ",");
   }
```

Any suggestion on how to handle this please?

Comment: n has no initial value in your snippet.  How do you know what the initial value is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't initialized the array, so if the loop only finds one number, you get whatever uninitialized garbage was in the second element.

```
int array[2] = {0, 0};
```

will initialize both elements to `0`. If the input has only `10`, the array will contain `10, 0`.